# Cant fire jQuery after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to fire this jQuery function when an ajax load completes, can anyone tell me why it won't fire?

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {  
    $('.testme').each(function () {
        var myhtml = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];
        var ele = $(this);
        $('.pickme').each(function(){
            myhtml == $(this).text().split(' ')[0] ? $(ele).css('display','block') : ""
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Removing one of those equal signs would probably help. `==` is a comparison operator, your want `=` as an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using two different jquery identifiers 'Jquery' and '$', try to use same.

Comment: That will have no effect; `$` is just a shortcut for `jQuery`.  They are interchangeable.

Comment: Also, not trying to be nasty, but this isn't an answer.  It should have been a comment.  Just trying to save you getting yourself downvoted :)